# java ListView showing content even after clearing

Tags: java, listview, javafx, javafx-8

Here is my code. I just want to display sub categories according to the selected category.
But it Just Changes the 1st line.

```
public void refreshSubCategoryHandle(ActionEvent E) throws Exception {
        this.listSubCategories.getItems().clear();
        ObservableList<SubCategory> olsc = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        olsc.clear();
        Connection con = (Connection) ConnectionClass.getConnection();
        String Sql = new String();
        Sql = "SELECT * FROM subCategory WHERE catId = '"+listCategories.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getCatId()+"'";
        Statement st = (Statement) con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rst = st.executeQuery(Sql);
        while(rst.next()) {
            System.out.println("SubCateGory : "+rst.getString("sCatName"));
            olsc.add(new SubCategory(rst.getInt("sCatId"), rst.getInt("catId") , rst.getString("sCatName"), rst.getString("sCatDescription"), rst.getInt("sCatRank"), rst.getString("sCatCreatedAt"), rst.getString("sCatUpdatedAt"), rst.getString("sCatAddedBy")));
            //SubCategoryList.add(ct);
        }
//      System.out.println(olsc.get(1));
//      observableSubCategories.addAll(SubCategoryList);
        this.listSubCategories.getItems().addAll(olsc);
    }
```

Every time this function is triggered it should only show the subcategories with category id 1 in list view but it is also displaying the data of other lists... (old data)

**Problem: It does not replace the whole old data but just 1 line of old data from the list view.**

Comment: Use `setAll(...)` instead of `addAll(...)`

Comment: `String Sql = new String(); Sql = "....` Don't do this. You're creating a new instance of the empty string only to replace it by the value you actually want to use. There is no point in doing the first assignment. Also better use `PreparedStatement` to prevent sql injection or breaking your own code, if you accidentally use a string containing a quote that isn't escaped properly... Also if `catId` is an int' why do you use quotes at all?